# Left Outer Join on Select Top 1 results in Nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

When I use the following code to join on the most recently updated address, it results in all associated fields in ZIP returning as NULL. I've tried an outer apply and it does a better job, but it doesn't not retrieve every single zip from the right two tables, even though they exist.

```
SELECT 
    i.ion_ID as [ION],
    zip.City as [City], 
    zip.StateCode as [State], 
    zip.ZipCode as [Zip Code], 
    zip.County as [County]
FROM     
    HWSP_t_ION i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 ad.AssociatedIDValue, z.Zipcode, z.City, z.StateCode, z.County
                                    FROM CADD_t_Address ad
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN CADD_lt_ZipCode z
                                            ON ad.zip = z.ZipCode
                                    ORDER BY ad.ChangedOn desc
                                        ) AS ZIP
        ON  zip.AssociatedIDValue = i.ION_ID
```

EDIT:
This is what the Outer Apply looked like:

```
SELECT 
    i.ion_ID as [ION],
    zip.City as [City], 
    zip.StateCode as [State], 
    zip.ZipCode as [Zip Code], 
    zip.County as [County]
OUTER APPLY                         (SELECT TOP 1 ad.zip
                                    FROM CADD_t_Address ad
                                    WHERE  ad.AssociatedIDValue = ci.ION_ID
                                    and [ad].[Status] = 'ACTIVE'
                                    ORDER BY ad.ChangedOn desc
                                        ) ad


OUTER APPLY                         (SELECT TOP 1 zip.Zipcode, zip.City, zip.StateCode, zip.County as [County]
                                    FROM CADD_lt_ZipCode zip
                                    WHERE ad.zip = zip.ZipCode
                                    ) zip
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if you would provider sample data and desired results

Comment: I wish I could but this is sensitive data with PII. The ION is the case number and it is pulling all 300k+ rows. The rest of the fields (zip.xxx) are all returning as null. So something is not joining correctly.

Comment: Try to break it down and de-PII it. If you can put it down into simpler terms, it may help you figure out where you need to be. Which version of SQL are you using. Try something like sqlfiddle to see if you can set up a basic example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @IrenaRich please provide sample data, to me it sound like a **WHERE** clause that you did not paste

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and don't know how to provide sample data. I'll show you what the outer apply looked like, if that helps..

Comment: My question has been edited to include the outer apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with SQL, think of your data in sets. Think of how you want the sets to combine. In this case, you just need 1 row of an inner set to get data for the outer set. Window functions work very well for the inner set. You're generating a row number (rn) to designate the 1st row in the sort, then eliminating anything not rn=1. Once you have that single most-recent record, then just link the two sets.

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID
    , s2.blah
    , s2.moreBlah
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT t2.id, t2.blah, t3.moreBlah
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY <columnToBaseOrderFrom> ORDER BY changeDate DESC ) AS rn
        FROM t2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2.refID = t3.id
    ) s1
    WHERE rn = 1
) s2 ON t1.id2 = s2.id
```

If you need to eliminate the NULL records, you'll have to determine if you want the rows from t1 to be eliminated if they don't have a match from the s2 subquery. If that's the case, you'll need INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: This worked! However, I'm still seeing the same nulls that I saw in the OUTER APPLY, so there must be some underlying, unrelated issue. I'll keep working on it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then you have rows in your `ZIP` subselect that don't match back up to your `HWSP_t_ION` table. Doublecheck that they should JOIN on `zip.AssociatedIDValue = i.ION_ID`. Also you can run each of the queries independently to see what is being returned. Final note: do you need an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Definitely left outer join, and to answer your earlier question, I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Then you have rows from your inner subselect that don't match to your outer select on zip.AssociatedIDValue = i.ION_ID. That's why you get `NULL`s.

Comment: Actually, I've gone through the transactional database and there are addresses, correctly entered into the correct fields. So it's something I'm doing wrong in the pull.

Comment: Take an `ion_ID` that is showing as `NULL` and code it into the inner query to see what you get. Syntactically, this is correct, so should return results if there is a match.  `SELECT count(*) as rowCounts FROM CADD_t_Address ad LEFT OUTER JOIN CADD_lt_ZipCode z ON ad.zip = z.ZipCode WHERE ad.AssociatedIDValue = <ion_ID you're searching>`.

Comment: I see two places where it can be breaking down. 1) `ad.zip = z.ZipCode` >> if CADD_lt_ZipCode isn't matching up with CADD_t_Address, you won't get data. And 2) `zip.AssociatedIDValue = i.ION_ID` >> if there isn't an associated record in you `ZIP` table, or if there wasn't a match in the inner, inner subselect (S1), then those records will return `NULL`. You also have an additional filter in your `OUTER APPLY` version: `[ad].[Status] = 'ACTIVE'`

Comment: I tracked down the issue using your rowCount query. The zip wasn't the best key to join on. I found a better way to link the tables using an address_ID and now its fully operational. Thanks, Shawn!